# Endogenous and exogenous ordinal variables in R studio Lavaan

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am new to using R studio, so apologies for the basic question. I have run a number of Confirmatory Factor Analyses using the Lavaan package. Each questionnaire item is on a 4 point Likert scale 0 = never, 1 = sometimes, 2 = often, 3 = always. I have treated items as exogenous ordinal variables. In the Lavaan description it says " If you have an exogenous ordinal variable, you can use a coding scheme reflecting the order (say, 1,2,3,. . . ) and treat it as any other (numeric) covariate."

However, I am now wondering whether it is more accurate to describe questionnaire items as endogenous ordinal variables using the 'ordered' function, or whether my model below is okay. If someone could also explain why this approach is/isn't optimal that would also be helpful.

Here is my model (one general factor and 3 specific sub factors):

```
library(lavaan)
Model <- " g =~ A_15 + A_19 + A_7 + A_13 + A_14 + A_29
                + A_20 + A_26 + A_30
               f1  =~ A_15 + A_19 + A_7
               f2  =~ A_20 + A_26 + A_30
               f3  =~ A_13 + A_14 + A_29"
fit <- cfa(Model, Data, estimator = "WLSMV", orthogonal = TRUE)
summary(fit, std=TRUE, fit.measures = TRUE)
```